# Could not get job jar and dependencies from JAR file: JAR file does not exist:

Tags: hadoop, jar, apache-flink, executable-jar

When I am submitting a file from hdfs to flink as a job , it is showing it "Could not get job jar and dependencies from JAR file: JAR file does not exist" but the file is preset in the given location and i am running in a single node cluster,command I am using to execute jar file

`- -\> ./flink run hdfs:///user/kirankathe/demo-helloworld-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`
And when i do `hdfs dfs -ls hdfs:///user/kirankathe/demo-helloworld-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`  this the output

```
- -\> -rwxrwxrwx   1 kirankathe supergroup       4316 2023-02-27 20:00 hdfs:///user/kirankathe/demo-helloworld-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I am using the following dependencies in my pom.xml file :
[image of pom.xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCSSR.png)

Are these dependencies enough or am I missing any configuration , is my approach correct , can any give your valuable suggestions regarding the issue.

Comment: I think you need to run a local JAR, so you need to `hdfs -get` it first. Then, if you are using YARN, it'll be uploded to the nodemanager filesystem, rather than HDFS

Comment: I want to execute the jar file which is in my hdfs , and my problem is that when i execute the same jar from local it is being execute and when i put that jar into the hadoop and try to execute with the hadoop path i am not able to execute that , and it is showing "Could not get job jar and dependencies from JAR file: JAR file does not exist"  but the file exists in the given location and all permissions are given to it.I tried with both executable and fat jar file.

Comment: Like I said, you cannot do that. It needs to be a local file. JAR files should realitically never be put into HDFS. You should put them in a Maven repo. Then you can try `flink run http://path/app.jar` ... Basically, `hdfs://` prefix cannot be resolved from `run` command, therefore "file does not exist"